# how to achive a working solution for Server Sent Event and bash script

Tags: php, bash, server-sent-events

I would like to implement a web page that show in real time the output of a bash script.

I tried this simple example:

html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;CHARSET=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
     <div id="result">put data out here</div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function eventsourcetest(){
           var source = new EventSource("http://localhost/prova_ping.php");
           source.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
           if (e.data !== "") {
              data=JSON.parse(e.data);                 
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML +=  e.data+ "<br>";
           }
           }, false);
           source.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
              alert("errore!");
              source.close();
           }, false);
        }    
     </script>
<p><button type="button" onclick="eventsourcetest();">ping google.com</button>
</body>
</html>
```

prova_ping.php:

```
<?php

  header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

  $proc = popen("ping -c4 www.google.com", 'r');
  while (!feof($proc))
  {
     echo "risultato: " . fread($proc, 4096) . "\n\n";flush();ob_flush();
  }

?>
```

checking the php page with the command:

```
wget -O - -q "http://localhost/prova_ping.php"
```

I get the output in real time, but when I load the html page in firefox and push the button, nothing is happening and I don't get any error from browser on from apache looking into the error.log.

Googling I have found many similar example, usualy on internal php command as time and all working fine but nothing about bash script exept this about ping that for me is not working!

If there are some one that can help me, any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank in advance,

Emilio

Comment: I'm impressed that you gave a *fully* reproducible example as your first question on this site!  (If you hadn't I wouldn't have bothered setting it up and debugging it.)

Comment: I am very glad to you for your quickly and "precise" answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

First change this line:

```
  echo "risultato: " . fread($proc, 4096) . "\n\n";flush();ob_flush();
```

into:

```
  echo "data " . fread($proc, 4096) . "\n\n";@ob_flush();@flush();
```

The key thing is the message has to be 'data'. (The standard does allow other messages, but is a feature that is never of practical use.)

I've put `ob_flush()` before `flush()`. (`ob_flush` is for the PHP buffers, so you need to flush them, before `flush()` which flushes the apache buffers.) The `@` just suppresses error messages - if you had the PHP buffers switched off, it would fill your output with noise.

The other fix you need to do is that you are not sending JSON data, so `JSON.parse()` causes an error. I just changed `data=JSON.parse(e.data);` to `data=e.data;`

Comment: Thank, I tried your solution and all working fine now !

Comment: @emiliodefranco Don't forget to upvote and/or tick it correct. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry ... how I can upvote ??

Comment: Click the up arrow (and it goes from grey to orange). To accept an answer click the grey tick, and it turns green. See also https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I tried, but the system tell me that I cannot because I not have 15 point of reputation ...